# How can I order a Django query against a custom list of values?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm populating a dropdown with values defined in my models.py, something like:

```
    rank_choices = (
        ('King', 'King')
        ('Prince', 'Prince')
        ('Duke', 'Duke')
        ('Baron', 'Baron')
        ('Lackey', 'Lackey')
```

When I'm displaying a list of people with a rank at a particular time, I want them to appear in descending rank.

Current query (merely alphabetic):

```
attendees = Rank.objects.filter(feast__id=feast__id).exclude(rank='Lackey').order_by('rank')
```

How could I change this to order rank by its position in the list?

I'm considering this:

```
    rank_choices = (
        (0, 'King')
        (1, 'Prince')
        (2, 'Duke')
        (3, 'Baron')
        (4, 'Lackey')
```

But even if I can get the verbose values back from the numeric values, any changes in the ordering would return incorrect values for data pre-change. Is there a better way?

**Chosen solution**

Inspired by wim's answer, I ended up doing a data migration to change the ranks to numeric values and sorting as follows.

```
ranks = sorted(ranks, key=lambda x: int(x.rank))
```

I'm getting the verbose values back by importing the rank_choices from my models into my views and replacing the numeric values with the corresponding titles after the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have `rank` stored in a CharField in database.  It's not simple to do a custom order_by without changing the schema.  Therefore, for simple cases, you may consider to make the ordering in python code:

```
rank_lookup = {rank: n for n,(rank,rank) in enumerate(rank_choices[::-1])}
ranks = Rank.objects.filter(...).values_list('rank', flat=1)
ranks = sorted(ranks, key=rank_lookup.get)
```

After the call to `sorted`, the queryset will be evaluated and you will have instead a python list.

If this is not satisfactory, it is possible (but not pretty) in the Django ORM to get the result you want in a queryset by using a `Case`/`When` construct:

```
>>> for rank, rank in rank_choices:
...     Rank.objects.create(rank=rank)
...     
>>> Rank.objects.order_by('rank')  # alphabetical
[<Rank: Baron>, <Rank: Duke>, <Rank: King>, <Rank: Lackey>, <Rank: Prince>]
>>> rank_lookup = {rank: n for n,(rank,rank) in enumerate(rank_choices)}
>>> cases = [When(rank=rank, then=Value(rank_lookup[rank])) for rank in rank_lookup]
>>> cases
[<When: WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rank', 'King'))> THEN Value(0)>,
 <When: WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rank', 'Lackey'))> THEN Value(4)>,
 <When: WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rank', 'Baron'))> THEN Value(3)>,
 <When: WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rank', 'Prince'))> THEN Value(1)>,
 <When: WHEN <Q: (AND: ('rank', 'Duke'))> THEN Value(2)>]
>>>
>>> Rank.objects.annotate(my_order=Case(*cases, output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('my_order')
[<Rank: King>, <Rank: Prince>, <Rank: Duke>, <Rank: Baron>, <Rank: Lackey>]
>>> Rank.objects.annotate(my_order=Case(*cases, output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('-my_order')
[<Rank: Lackey>, <Rank: Baron>, <Rank: Duke>, <Rank: Prince>, <Rank: King>]
```

Thanks to user "mu is too short" in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703590/how-can-i-order-a-django-query-against-a-custom-list-of-values/36703898?noredirect=1#comment60998470_36703898) for inspiring this idea.  This will work in Django 1.8+ because of the new features in [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

For users unfortunate enough to be stuck on older versions of Django, the same idea is possible by constructing a raw sql fragment to pass in using [`Queryset.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this. I will need to display some other attributes of the Rank object and its fk objects, but maybe I can leave out the flat=1, give multiple columns to values_list and work with that.

Comment: Yep, just modify the argument passed to `key` in the sorted call

Comment: Can't you specify an ORDER BY expression with Django? `order by case rank when 'King' then 0 when 'Prince' then 1 ... end` for example. SQL lets you order by any valid expression, not just columns.

Comment: @muistooshort  I honestly don't know.  If you can get it working, post an answer :)

Comment: I know SQL but very little Django. The `order_by('rank')` in the OP's code suggests that `order_by` is happy with a string argument so maybe `order_by('case rank when ...')` would work. Alternatively, you could JOIN to a two column table with rank names and numbers and order by the JOINed number, that would probably be cleaner inside Django and require less string wrangling and escaping.

Comment: There is some Django ORM context you are missing here.  The 'rank' string in the `order_by` call would refer to the name of a `CharField` on a Django model.  There is metaclass magic that turns this into actual SQL.  Using any old string there would almost certainly raise a `FieldError` exception.  Of course, you would have to have familiarity with Django to implicitly know these things.  ;)

Comment: But the `CharField` in the model is just a column (named `rank`) inside the database so it would depend on how clever the ORM is versus how clever it thinks it is. You'd think there'd be a way to get around the pseudo-cleverness but I don't know Django. You might want to change that "I don't think it's possible, that's a SQL limitation not a Django limitation." statement as it appears to be exactly wrong :)

Comment: You can't do it by trying to trick the Django ORM using strings, because they are very careful with all that stuff to avoid sql injection attacks.  But I found a way to do it using the conditional expressions you've suggested.